# Separation axioms and compactness

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a regular topological space, and $A$ is a compact subset, and $U$ is a neighbourhood of $A$

Then there is a closed neighbourhood $V$ of $A$ such that $V \subset U$

Why does this imply that each compact regular space is normal?

I am well aware of one of the standard definitions of being regular, e.g.

for some $x \notin B$ where $B$ is a closed set $\exists$ disjoint open sets $U,V$ containing $x$ and $B$

and another definition that I have learned which is a result from a lemma is:

$X$ is regular $\iff$ for $x \in X$ and a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ $\exists$ a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ s.t. $\bar{V} \subset U$.

I think the lemma definition is kind of close to answering my own question, but then again they are not similar?

Note that I am not asking a proof of this statement I am asking for why this is enough to show normality.

Comment: To understand why it is enough you have to understand the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Take a compact regular space X and two disjoint closed subsets of it, namely $A$ and $B$. Then $A$ is compact and $U= X \setminus B$ is a neighbourhood of $A$. Now your statement gives a $V$ such that $A \subset V \subset \bar V\subset U$. So $V$ and $X \setminus \bar V$ are the needed disjoint open sets seperating $A$ and $B$.